# Asp.net c# table to insert time from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a training system in **Asp.net** coded in **C#** that will allow **administrator** to create a training on the backend , then different session times 
for example training:customer service, training date, **01/01/2012.**

**Different times**

```
7:00 am - 11:00 am,     
2:00 pm - 6:00 pm,
6:30 pm - 11:00pm
```

But I am not sure which way to go on the training times portion of it since a training can have different multiple times . 
How should I design the time field on the table in the database, and the dropdownlist,?
my thought is to have a dropdown prepopulated with times from 07:00 to 23:00 , for start and ending dates, but not sure that would be the best thing?

Comment: You need to break this down into separate questions, and show us what you have done so far. StackOverflow is for answering specific questions, not for long briefings on how to build a particular app.

Comment: I think you are right, I should only ask one at time

Comment: Are there only three sessions per day?  If so, you could assign each session an integer value and use the time ranges as the dropdown labels only.

Comment: The maximum sessions per day are 3 ,yes, but the times might vary, are you suggesting creating a third table with the times ?

Comment: Possibly.  I think it may be cleaner to have a concept of sessions in the database, with start and end times.  Then each training session will have a date, userID, and sessionID rather than start and start and end times.  There's not enough info in your question to know if that's best, but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep total minutes e.g. (from 00:00 to 07:00) and keep in a integer field.
and you can use `TimeSpan` object to convert values.

Comment: What would be the data type on the db table column?

Comment: How would I populate the dropdown lists ?

Comment: You can have two int column for start and end time, also you can convert int value to string as `DateTime.MinValue.AddMinutes(256).ToString("hh:mm tt");` to populate the dropdown.